# It possible to style the filterToolbar in a jqGrid?

Tags: css, jqgrid, css-selectors

I am using jqGrid and want to know if it is possible to style the background of the filterToolbar separately from the rest of the grid.

I've tried:

```
var $search_toolbar = $("tr.ui-search-toolbar", $("#list")[0].grid.hDiv);
$search_toolbar.css('height', '50');
$search_toolbar.css('background-color', 'Red');
```

The height get set, but the background-color appears to be overridden by child TH elements.

I then tried creating a style:

```
tr.ui-search-toolbar th{
    height:30px;
    background-color:Black;
    background-image:none;
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, I just can't see what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like the following

```
.ui-jqgrid table.ui-jqgrid-htable th.ui-th-column input,
.ui-jqgrid table.ui-jqgrid-htable th.ui-th-column select {
    background-color: red
}
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithSearchingToolbarStyled.htm).